# Get the typename T from outside the template class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector that I want to wrap in some additional functionality:

```
template <typename T>
class PersistentVector : PersistentObject
{
  private:
    std::vector<T> values;

  public:
    virtual void read();
```

Now, how would I go about defining read() outside the class if it must know the typename T?

**First try:**

```
void PersistentVector::read()
{
  // How can I get the iterator type?
  typedef std::vector<T>::iterator it_type;  // vector cannot be resolved
}
```

**Second try:**

```
// error: Member declaration not found
template <typename T>
void PersistentVector::read()
{
  typedef std::vector<T>::iterator it_type;  // no error
}
```

Comment: You actually should get an error in the second try. You need a `typename`. Perhaps your compiler is not compliant.

Comment: `typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator it_type;` -- looks like @juanchopanza beat me to it :-)

Comment: That's a templated function that you want to use, you need to either move the body into the header or declare the types you want to use explicitly in the cpp file

Comment: <cheapshot>It's written `auto`</cheapshot>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second try is almost there. You got the syntax slightly wrong, and are missing a `typename`. Note the `PersistentVector<T>::`:

```
template <typename T>
void PersistentVector<T>::read()
{
  typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator it_type;  // no error
}
```

Note that this definition must be accessible to any code using it. Usually this means it has to be in the header file, or in a file included by the header.

Alternatively, you can put the method definition inside of the class definition:

```
public:
  virtual void read()
  {
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator it_type;
  }
```

Comment: is it into a .h file or .cpp file? That's different

Comment: @DavidKernin I added a note. It should not be in a .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

It is mandatory that the type of the template is known at the POI (point-of-instantiation) before linking time, so you should either put that into the header (and watch out for the *typename* keyword, it is required in that case):

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class PersistentVector
{
  private:
    std::vector<T> values;

  public:
    virtual void read() {
      typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator it_type;
    }
};
```

Or do something like an explicit instantiation

.h file

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class PersistentVector
{
  private:
    std::vector<T> values;

  public:
    virtual void read();
};
```

.cpp file

```
#include "headerfile.h"

template <typename T>
void PersistentVector<T>::read()
{
  typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator it_type; 
}

template class PersistentVector<int>;
```